# vite throws file not found error when bootstrap5 added to sveltekit app.html

Tags: bootstrap-5, svelte, sveltekit

I added bootstrap5 via style and script tags in app.html

bs5 works fine but vite throws error that files are not found.

any advice?

Error message

> Error: Not found: /vendors/bootstrap-5.0.2/bootstrap.min.css.map

> Error: Not found: /vendors/bootstrap-5.0.2/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map

files located:

/static/vendors/bootstrap-5.0.2/bootstrap.min.scss

/static/vendors/bootstrap-5.0.2/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend adding anything to the `app.html`, instead import from a root `+layout.svelte`, installing `bootstrap` from NPM.

The errors refer to `.map` files that specify what parts of a minified JS file refer to which lines in a source file. You probably did not copy the files over, so they cannot be found. The files are reference from the `.min.js` files.

But as noted, one should not import scripts like that.

---

When installing from NPM you need the packages:

- `bootstrap`
- `@popperjs/core`

It is possible to import just the code for specific components and compile the CSS from source ([see docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/#import-bootstrap)). To import *all* code and styles you just need:

```html
<script>
    import 'bootstrap';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
</script>
```

It is preferred to only import what is actually needed to reduce the resulting bundle size.

Comment: could you advice what code to put in? i am very new to this. coming from nuxt2. there 2 files bootstrap.min.scss and bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: There is some [documentation on that](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/#import-bootstrap). You should use direct imports and ideally limit what you import to just what you use. `.min` files should not be used anyway if you have a build chain.